# Express.js Res redirect issue when using Backbone.js, hashtag urls not redirecting

Tags: javascript, node.js, backbone.js, express

**Summary**

- Express.js redirect not working correctly.
- res.redirect fires and works correctly when i type in /impulse/ but not when i type in /#impulse.
- When i type in /#impulse the server goes off and gets the information before applying redirect checks, however it doesn't seem to redirect.

Details below:

I have a current problem my web app not redirecting users to the login screen

I've changed the code a bit so that the app.all catches everything with /impulse/ in:

```
app.all('/impulse*', function(req, res, next){   isImpulse = true;
console.log('force redirect: ', isImpulse );
next();
});
```

For the purpose of testing i've taken out the res.redirect and put it in my router and made it set a global boolean to true by default because at first I thought "app.all" wasn't firing or working correctly.

So what happens now is, when the next part of my routing fires it checks the boolean like so:

```
app.get('/impulse', function(req,res){
if(isImpulse){
    console.log('enforce redirect');
    res.redirect('/auth/login');
    return;
} else {  impulse.findAll}

} );
```

What I've found is quite interesting.

If i use /impulse/ i get redirected, however if i Use /#impulse/ the console **spits out 'enforce redirect' but it doesn't redirect... Even though res.redirect is directly below this console echo...**

Now i've tried changing all sorts to "app.all" (Because I thought this was initially the problem) but the way I've changed the code it makes it impossible for "app.all" to be the problem. The problem is simply that res.redirect doesn't seem to be firing when /#impulse/ is used.

I've included two pictures of my servers' console chatter. The first one is when i enter /impulse/ (note that this one works correctly, you can see in the console log "**enforce redirect** then it goes off and gets the relevant stuff):
[image: The redirect kicks in when it gets to **enfore redirect**]

Now this second picture is when I type in /#impulse/ the console still spits out **enforce redirect** but spits out stuff it shouldn't before checking redirect rules...

[image: This image doesn't redirect]

Obviously this is a security problem. SO what does it display when I type in /#impulse you ask? The headers and footers display but not the content. (None of this should display by the way).

So what am I doing wrong guys, is the backbone front end going off and getting this stuff without even going through server security checks? **Note: app.all has been put at the top of the router, it -should- always fire first!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If i use /impulse/ i get redirected,

That's because your code is returning the proper response (i.e. a redirect) and the BROWSER knows how to interpret it and redirect the user to the page indicated in the response.

> however if i Use /#impulse/ the console spits out 'enforce redirect' but it doesn't 
>   redirect... Even though res.redirect is directly below this console echo...

This is very likely a problem in your CLIENT SIDE JavaScript code. When you make an AJAX call you usually need to manually evaluate the response and manually follow the redirect indicated in the response. I am not exactly sure how this works with Backbone but the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

After about a week of head banging I've found out what the problem is...

Its true this was client side, I was overlooking a very simple feature, browsers don't send # urls to the server so for example mysite.com/#admin will simply look up the dom for a div element with an id of admin, it wont send a request off to the server.

This explains everything, including why i was getting half loaded pages, because backbone would load the static stuff then request the juicy bits from the server, but the server would deny any more info!

I'm still scratching my head on how best to fix this, but now that I've had an enlightened moment, I thought I better share it with everyone incase people have the same problem as me.

Also, suggestions for a fix are welcome!